# Is there anyway to use axios to check form without click submit?

Tags: reactjs, ajax, promise, axios

I have a form register like in the picture and check **username** and **email** that is already used

[image]

For now, I use **axios** to send requests to Backend and throw exceptions back and show the popup that `username already use`

[image]

To improved user experience, I don't want to click submit and show the popup. Is there any way to show validation instantly after filling the form? **(without submit form)**

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the security risk that this brings to your application depending on it's usage. Your app likely shouldn't inform other uses if an email is already in use specifically.

You could run your code that makes the axios call for those fields on change. You'd make a new function, and add it to the onChange of the input.

Without seeing your code it's a little challenging.

```
handleOnChange = () => {
*whatever you want to happen on change probably your axios call*
}

<form>
<label>whatever</label>
<input onChange={handleOnChange} />
</form>
```

The handleOnChange might need braces or to be called using a call back, I can't recall sorry!

Comment: you probably gonna need to pass in a variable from onchange to the function so it will be `<input onChange={(e: any) =>handleOnChange(e)} />` dont forget `e.persist()` in the function as well